# Flutter and Signalr : The underlying connection was closed before the hub handshake could complete

Tags: asp.net, flutter, websocket, signalr

iam trying to open socket connection in flutter with signalr
this is the code in flutter :

```
import 'package:fpdart/fpdart.dart';
import 'package:fxtweet/application/provider/sharedpref.provider.dart';
import 'package:fxtweet/domain/failures/api.failures.dart';
import 'package:fxtweet/domain/hub/interface/i.hub.repository.dart';
import 'package:hooks_riverpod/hooks_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:logging/logging.dart';
import 'package:signalr_netcore/ihub_protocol.dart';
import 'package:signalr_netcore/signalr_client.dart';
// import 'package:signal/signalr_client.dart';

class HubRepository extends IHubRepository {
  final Ref ref;

  HubRepository({required this.ref});

  @override
  Future<Either<ApiFailures, bool>> startHub() async {
    Logger.root.level = Level.ALL;
// Writes the log messages to the console
    Logger.root.onRecord.listen((LogRecord rec) {
      print('${rec.level.name}: ${rec.time}: ${rec.message}');
    });
    final transportProtLogger = Logger("SignalR - transport");
    final hubProtLogger = Logger("SignalR - hub");

    final defaultHeaders = MessageHeaders();
    defaultHeaders.setHeaderValue("Authorization",
        '${await ref.read(settingsNotifierProvider.notifier).getToken()}');
    defaultHeaders.setHeaderValue('Connection', 'Upgrade');
    defaultHeaders.setHeaderValue('Upgrade', 'websocket');
    defaultHeaders.setHeaderValue('Sec-WebSocket-Version', '13');
    defaultHeaders.setHeaderValue('Sec-WebSocket-Extensions',
        'permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits');

    final connection = HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl('https://xxxxxxxxx',
            options: HttpConnectionOptions(
              headers: defaultHeaders,
              logger: hubProtLogger,
            ))
        .withAutomaticReconnect()
        .build();
    try {
      await connection.start();
      return right(true);
    } catch (error) {
      // await connection.start();

      print(error.toString());
      print(connection.state);

      return left(const ApiFailures.authFailed());
    }
  }
}
```

and this is the signalr code :

```
using FxTweet.App.Server.Code.Interfaces.ServicesInterfaces;
using FxTweet.App.Server.Code.Utils.Auth;
using FxTweet.App.Shared.Enums;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using SignalRSwaggerGen.Attributes;

namespace FxTweet.App.Server.Hubs;

/// <summary>
/// Handles the live feed hub.
/// </summary>
/// <seealso cref="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Hub" />
[SignalRHub(tag: "SignalR/Hubs/LiveFeedHub", description: "Provides Live feed data")]
//[Authorize]
[NxAuthorizePermission(SystemPolicies.canNavigateAsProvider, SystemPolicies.canNavigateAsGuest, SystemPolicies.canNavigateAsMember)]
public class LiveFeedHub : Hub<ILiveFeedHub>
{
    private readonly ILiveFeedService liveFeedService;
    private readonly ISymbolService symbolService;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="LiveFeedHub"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="liveFeedService">The live feed service.</param>
    public LiveFeedHub(ILiveFeedService liveFeedService, ISymbolService symbolService)
    {
        this.liveFeedService = liveFeedService;
        this.symbolService = symbolService;
    }

    ///// <summary>
    ///// Sends the specified live feed model.
    ///// </summary>
    ///// <param name="liveFeedModel">The live feed model.</param>
    //[NxAuthorizePermission(Policies = new[] { SystemPolicies.canNavigateAsProvider, SystemPolicies.canNavigateAsGuest, SystemPolicies.canNavigateAsMember })]
    //public async Task SendLiveFeed(CNxLiveFeedModel liveFeedModel)
    //{
    //    // static Task SendAsync(this IClientProxy clientProxy, string method, object? arg1, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)

    //    await Clients.Group("LiveFeedSubscribes").SendLiveFeedAsync(liveFeedModel);
    //    await Clients.All.SendLiveFeedAsync(liveFeedModel);
    //}

    /// <summary>
    /// Called when a new connection is established with the hub.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// A <see cref="T:System.Threading.Tasks.Task" /> that represents the asynchronous connect.
    /// </returns>
    [SignalRHidden]
    public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        this.Context.Items.Add("ConnectionId", this.Context.ConnectionId);
        return base.OnConnectedAsync();
    }

    // [NxAuthorizePermission(SystemPolicies.canNavigateAsProvider, SystemPolicies.canNavigateAsGuest, SystemPolicies.canNavigateAsMember)]
    /// <summary>
    /// Joins the group.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="symbolIds">The pair names.</param>
    [SignalRMethod(summary: "Joins symbols feed")]
    public async Task JoinLiveFeed([SignalRParam] long[] symbolIds)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < symbolIds.Length; i++)
        {
            var symbolId = symbolIds[i];
            await this.Groups.AddToGroupAsync(this.Context.ConnectionId, $"LiveSubscribersGroup_Symbol_{symbolId}");
        }

        await Clients.Caller.SendLiveFeedAsync($"You are now subscribed to new {symbolIds.Length} symbols");
        await Clients.Caller.SendLiveFeedAsync($"Symbols List:");
        await Clients.Caller.SendSymbolsListAsync(symbolService.GetByIds(symbolIds));
        await Clients.Caller.SendLiveFeedAsync($"Current Feed:");
        await Clients.Caller.SendAllLiveFeedAsync(liveFeedService.GetByIds(symbolIds));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Joins the group.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="symbolIds">The pair names.</param>
    [SignalRMethod(summary: "SignalR Only: Joins symbols feed")]
    public async Task LeaveLiveFeed([SignalRParam] params int[] symbolIds)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < symbolIds.Length; i++)
        {
            var symbolId = symbolIds[i];
            await this.Groups.RemoveFromGroupAsync(this.Context.ConnectionId, $"LiveSubscribersGroup_Symbol_{symbolId}");
        }

        await Clients.Caller.SendLiveFeedAsync($"You are now un-subscribed from {symbolIds.Length} symbols");
    }
}
```

it is working in postman and connecting as it should but in flutter it throws this error :

```
FINER: 2023-12-26 22:29:13.976991: Starting connection with transfer format 'TransferFormat.Text'.
I/flutter (12212): FINER: 2023-12-26 22:29:13.990736: Sending negotiation request: https://app.fxtweet.com/hubs/livefeed/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1
D/EGL_emulation(12212): app_time_stats: avg=9561.66ms min=9561.66ms max=9561.66ms count=1
I/flutter (12212): FINEST: 2023-12-26 22:29:14.372295: HTTP send: url 'https://app.fxtweet.com/hubs/livefeed/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1', method: 'POST' content: '' content length = '0' headers: '{ Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits }, { Connection: Upgrade }, { content-type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8 }, { Upgrade: websocket }, { X-Requested-With: FlutterHttpClient }, { Authorization: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.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
I/flutter (12212): FINER: 2023-12-26 22:29:14.978053: Selecting transport 'HttpTransportType.WebSockets'.
I/flutter (12212): FINEST: 2023-12-26 22:29:14.983804: (WebSockets transport) Connecting
I/flutter (12212): FINEST: 2023-12-26 22:29:14.990027: WebSocket try connecting to 'wss://app.fxtweet.com/hubs/livefeed?id=ffQqvTRQYa5-YBU_Vpd79A'.
I/flutter (12212): INFO: 2023-12-26 22:29:15.006449: WebSocket connected to 'wss://app.fxtweet.com/hubs/livefeed?id=ffQqvTRQYa5-YBU_Vpd79A'.
I/flutter (12212): FINER: 2023-12-26 22:29:15.013541: The HttpConnection connected successfully.
I/flutter (12212): FINEST: 2023-12-26 22:29:15.024656: (WebSockets transport) sending data. String data of length 32. Content: '{"protocol":"json","version":1}'.
E/flutter (12212): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: WebSocketException: Connection to 'https://app.fxtweet.com:0/hubs/livefeed?id=ffQqvTRQYa5-YBU_Vpd79A#' was not upgraded to websocket
E/flutter (12212): #0      _WebSocketImpl.connect (dart:_http/websocket_impl.dart:1011:41)
E/flutter (12212): #1      WebSocket.connect (dart:_http/websocket.dart:320:22)
E/flutter (12212): #2      new IOWebSocketChannel.connect (package:web_socket_channel/io.dart:81:28)
E/flutter (12212): #3      connect (package:web_socket_channel/src/_connect_io.dart:15:24)
E/flutter (12212): #4      new WebSocketChannel.connect (package:web_socket_channel/src/channel.dart:115:16)
E/flutter (12212): #5      WebSocketTransport.connect (package:signalr_netcore/web_socket_transport.dart:53:35)
E/flutter (12212): #6      HttpConnection._startTransport (package:signalr_netcore/http_connection.dart:574:24)
E/flutter (12212): #7      HttpConnection._createTransport (package:signalr_netcore/http_connection.dart:529:15)
E/flutter (12212): #8      HttpConnection._startInternal (package:signalr_netcore/http_connection.dart:409:15)

E/flutter (12212): #9      HttpConnection.start (package:signalr_netcore/http_connection.dart:255:5)
E/flutter (12212): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (12212): #10     HubConnection._startInternal (package:signalr_netcore/hub_connection.dart:222:5)
E/flutter (12212): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (12212): #11     HubConnection._startWithStateTransitions (package:signalr_netcore/hub_connection.dart:204:7)
E/flutter (12212): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (12212): 
I/flutter (12212): FINER: 2023-12-26 22:29:15.342069: HttpConnection.stopConnection(Unknown) called while in state ConnectionState.Connected.
I/flutter (12212): INFO: 2023-12-26 22:29:15.342650: Connection disconnected.
I/flutter (12212): FINER: 2023-12-26 22:29:15.348301: Call to HttpConnection.stop(Exception: The underlying connection was closed before the hub handshake could complete.) ignored because the connection is already in the disconnected state.
E/flutter (12212): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: The underlying connection was closed before the hub handshake could complete.
```

i have literally tried everything with no use at all, the connections starts ok but when it starts sending the handshake it falls apart like that , any suggestions ?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you find a fix?

Comment: @katkak iam sorry for the late response but my issue was from the backend